# How to include libraries hosted on Github in a C++ project? (New C++ user - previously used language with package manager)

Tags: c++, repository, open-source, directory-structure

I want to include [uWebSockets](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets) in a C++ project and I am unclear on how to do this. I've compiled projects with `.so` dependencies, when it comes to projects listed on github I am still confused.

Specifically:

- Does the third-party repository need to be compiled prior to including it in my project?
- Where to store the library in the source code directory?
- How to link the source code with third-party libraries?
- Are tools such as CMake needed?

Apologies in advance if these questions seem obvious or silly, I come from a language with a package manager so this is rather new to me.

**Update**

Following the "Getting Started" instruction in the Github repository, upon cloning the repository, making sure that the dependencies are installed and running `make`, the following output is observed:

```
dave@desktop:~/gitrepositories/uWebSockets$ make
make `(uname -s)`
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/dave/gitrepositories/uWebSockets'
g++   -std=c++11 -O3 -I src -shared -fPIC src/Extensions.cpp src/Group.cpp src/Networking.cpp src/Hub.cpp src/Node.cpp src/WebSocket.cpp src/HTTPSocket.cpp src/Socket.cpp src/Epoll.cpp -s -o libuWS.so
In file included from src/WebSocketProtocol.h:5:0,
                 from src/WebSocket.h:4,
                 from src/Group.h:4,
                 from src/Group.cpp:1:
src/Networking.h:7:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/Networking.cpp:1:0:
src/Networking.h:7:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/WebSocketProtocol.h:5:0,
                 from src/WebSocket.h:4,
                 from src/Group.h:4,
                 from src/Hub.h:4,
                 from src/Hub.cpp:1:
src/Networking.h:7:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/Socket.h:4:0,
                 from src/Node.h:4,
                 from src/Node.cpp:1:
src/Networking.h:7:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/WebSocketProtocol.h:5:0,
                 from src/WebSocket.h:4,
                 from src/WebSocket.cpp:1:
src/Networking.h:7:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/Socket.h:4:0,
                 from src/HTTPSocket.h:4,
                 from src/HTTPSocket.cpp:1:
src/Networking.h:7:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/Socket.h:4:0,
                 from src/Socket.cpp:1:
src/Networking.h:7:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'Linux' failed
make[1]: *** [Linux] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dave/gitrepositories/uWebSockets'
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Comment: You need to read the documentation for each project.

Comment: I installed the dependencies for `uWebSocket` according to their "Getting Started" `README.md` on Github. When running `make` from the folder I received a lot of errors and a terminated compilation - my assumption is that I am doing something wrong and that I do not understand the concept.

Comment: I just tried this with `git clone https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets`, `make`, `make installLinux`. No surprises here. What exactly are the "lot of errors" in your case? Do you work on Linux, Windows, or OSX?

Comment: @Dave Before running `make` you usually have to run the `configure` script.

Comment: @user0042 Where can I find the `configure` script?

Comment: @OlafDietsche I've updated the post to show the output I get after running `make`

Comment: @Dave It should be part of the package.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Forgot to mention that I am running Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Comment: @Dave Apparently there's no `configure` script. So did you follow their instructions regarding installation of the dependencies?

Comment: @user0042 All sorted now thanks - looks like it was a missing dependency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to answer the questions:

> Does the third-party repository need to be compiled prior to including it in my project?

Yes, you must compile the library before, because you cannot link your program without the library.

> Where to store the library in the source code directory?

```
make install
```

will take care of this.

> How to link the source code with third-party libraries?

You don't link the source code, but your object files together with the libraries to form an executable. This looks more or less like

```
g++ -o sample main.o second.o more.o -L/path/to/libs -luWS -lmorelibs
```

> Are tools such as CMake needed?

Not in this case, `uWebSockets` uses just make, nothing else.

---

The error messages are about missing header files. This means, you must install the appropriate developer packages for the prerequisites, namely openssl and zlib.

For Debian/Ubuntu this is done by

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev zlib1g-dev
```